# Is there a way to adjust volume in MPMoviePlayer Controller by program?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to increase or decrease or even mute the volume of movie player by my program instead of the buttons in Movie player. Is there a way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no public API to control these settings through software. If you'd like to have this kind of control I'd recommend filing a bug with the Apple developer connection.