# Volume control in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, volume

I am trying to figure out how to adjust the volume of a movie played with MPMoviePlayerController on the iPhone without using the slider or the volume buttons on the side of the phone.  Is it even possible to do this with code in a Apple approved way?  I haven't been able to find anything in the APIs that relate to changing or setting the volume during movie playback.

I know a similar question was asked a little over a year ago ([Is there a way to adjust volume in MPMoviePlayer Controller by program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959908/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-volume-in-mpmovieplayer-controller-by-program)), but I wanted to know if anyone had found a way to change the volume in MPMoviePlayerController since then.

Comment: [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:<Value from 0.0 to 1.0>];